# Which characters are healers?

Tags: overwatch

The game suggests that a team should have at least one healer - who are the "healers" exactly? Is everyone in the support class a healer?

**Note**: I'm not asking which characters can heal, I want to know which characters are labeled as "healers" by the game.

Answer (score 6):

The only healers (in alphabetical order) are:

**[Ana](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/ana/)**

**[Lucio](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/lucio/)**

**[Mercy](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/mercy/)**

**[Zenyatta](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/zenyatta/)**

Those are the heroes whose main purpose/abilities/ultimate is to restore health to allied players.

This said, there are some other heroes that can provide HP support in some way. Soldier has a BIOTIC FIELD which heals anyone in small range for few seconds.

And Sombra can hack health packs to provide increased HP heal from them.

**Only the four mentioned heroes above are classified as healers in the game, and it would be their main job to heal and restore health.**

Symetra may be in the support section but she's not a "healer" she's a builder alongside Torbjorn. As mentioned in the comments bellow, the different classifications are very arbitrary and many heroes can fit more than one section. For instance Sombra could have been placed as a Support hero just as easily. Or Symetra could have been a defence hero or Roadhog could have been an offensive hero.

Comment: You say "no order" but that looks a lot like alphabetical order.

Comment: @Yuuki You got me ...

Comment: You might want to mention [Symmetra](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/symmetra/) as she is the fifth support character (but not a healer).

Comment: Just say that "healers are", I tested by selecting characters when the "no healers" warning was present and 4/5 of the support characters remove the notification, Symmetra does not.

Comment: @user598527 That's because she's a builder. But even Jeff the game designer said that these little notifications at the start of the game are there just to help the very new players. I stopped looking at them after about 20-30 levels. The same dude also said that the roles, the heroes have are more arbitrary. Sombra could have just as easily been put as a support hero, and Symetra could have been a Defence hero.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the game is trying to convey the message that "healers" are useful - that is to say, it is useful for each team to have at least one character that can heal other players.

**"Healer" as a Role**

According to [this thread](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20749898116), the main "healers" are: **Mercy**, **Lucio**, **Ana** (if the player is exceptional with her), and **Zenyatta**. This is also verified by the Roles page on the [wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Healer#Healer).

**"Healer" in the Common Vernacular**

However, more generally, I think that any player that can heal could be classified as a "healer" in the context of the statement you read (though we would need the exact statement to verify this is the case). Nevertheless, the characters that can heal can be found on the [wiki](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Hit_points#Ally_Healing):

> **[Ana](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ana)**'s Biotic Rifle can heal an ally for 75 over 0.9 seconds. Biotic Grenade also heals all allies for 100 and boosts other sources of healing by 50% with an area effect of 4 meters.
>   She can hit herself with the grenade, receiving its positive effects.
>
> **[Lúcio](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/L%C3%BAcio)**'s Crossfade, when toggled to healing mode, passively heals
>   allies and himself within 30 meters (as long as line-of-sight is
>   maintained) for 12.5 hit points per second, or 36 hit points per
>   second during Amp It Up.
>
> **[Mercy](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Mercy)**'s Caduceus Staff can heal an ally for 60 hit points per second
>   while they remain within 15 meters and maintains line of sight.
>
> **[Soldier: 76](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Soldier:_76)**'s Biotic Field heals allies within 5 meters for 40 hit
>   points per second. Biotic Field also heals Soldier: 76 at the same
>   rate if he is within range.
>
> **[Sombra](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Sombra)**'s Hack causes Health Packs to respawn 4x faster, with healing
>   from Hacked Health Packs being credited to Sombra as healing done.
>
> **[Zenyatta](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Zenyatta)**'s Orb of Harmony heals the targeted ally for 30 hit points
>   per second. Transcendence heals all allies within 10 meters for 300
>   hit points per second (duration 6 seconds). Transcendence also heals
>   Zenyatta in addition to making him invulnerable to damage.

**All Support Characters are NOT Healers**

No, not all support characters are healers. [Symmetra](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Symmetra) is support, though she cannot heal. As her [wiki page states](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Symmetra#Trivia):

> Symmetra is the only Support hero that is not a healer.

Comment: Thank you, but I asked who are "healers", not which characters can heal.

Comment: Assuming that the game doesn't consider everyone who can heal as a "healer" - apparently not: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309997/148510

Comment: Right, I think that I am saying that any character that can heal others would be considered a "healer", though I can update my answer with preferred healers in competitive play if that's more what you're looking for.

Comment: @user598527 I can edit my answer to better reflect this if that is more what you are asking

Comment: @user598527: I'm not looking for preferred healers either, see my updated question. If anyone who can heal indeed is a healer, you're correct.

Comment: @user598527 I've updated my answer to include links to a battle.net forum and the Overwatch wiki confirming that "healers" include Mercy, Lucio, Ana, and Zenyatta, though I still think that using characters like Soldier or Sombra would still satisfy the common vernacular of having a healer on your team.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59511/discussion-between-user598527-and-b-s-morganstein).

Comment: @user598527 i saw in the chat you were thinking of giving the other answer the credit, but in all fairness, this should get it as it has the correct answer and extra context, as well as (here's the main bit) proper citation.